# VBA Multi File Copy to specific folder

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to copy the all selected cell (including the file Source Path) to a target folder after I use the Text Filters function. The Source path format is Z:\test\123456\xxx.pdf, then the target folder is on cell N1 “Z:\test2\”. I have developed the below program but shows the error “Path/File access error (Error 75)”. I have tried many different path patterns, but still can’t work…

```
Sub CopyFiles()
Dim SourcePath As String
Dim TargetPath As String
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
    SourcePath = Selection.Cells(i, "K").Value
    TargetPath = Range("N1").Value
    FileCopy SourcePath & Selection.Cells(i, "K").Value, TargetPath & Selection.Cells(i, "K").Value
Next i
MsgBox "Copy Completed。"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using `Selection`? Are you highlighting entire rows before running this?

Comment: Also, your `FileCopy` line should probably just be `FileCopy SourcePath , TargetPath`

Answer (score 0):

If you add some lines that output to the debug window, you might see what is going wrong:

```
Sub CopyFiles()
    Dim SourcePath As String
    Dim TargetPath As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
        SourcePath = Selection.Cells(i, "K").Value
        TargetPath = Range("N1").Value
        Debug.Print "Copying from: [" & SourcePath & "]"
        Debug.Print "Copying to  : [" & TargetPath & "]" & Chr(13)
        'FileCopy SourcePath, TargetPath
    Next i
    MsgBox "Copy Completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank for your teach me the debug function, i'm newcomer for VBA. I made it with below program.
`
Sub GetSelectedValues()
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Set selectedRange = Selection
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In selectedRange
        Debug.Print cell.Value
        SourcePath = cell.Value
        Debug.Print "Copying from: [" & SourcePath & "]"
        TargetPath = Range("N1").Value
        Debug.Print "Copying to  : [" & TargetPath & "]" & Chr(13)
        FileCopy SourcePath, TargetPath & "\" & Dir(SourcePath)
    Next cell
End Sub
`

Comment: I'm not sure why you're FileCopy destination is `TargetPath & "\" & Dir(SourcePath)` - it should just be `TargetPath`